# BlueJ Java Issue

Tags: java, bluej

I have some problems with my ice cream project.

When I use the accessor methods in the topping and ice cream classes to return the string values, they don't return them. I don't  notice any problems with the code.

When I go onto the Sundae class to enter the details of the icecream and topping it comes up with this message.​

> Error: Incompatible Types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to IceCream.

Here is the code for the IceCream, Topping and Sundae classes:

#### IceCream.java

```
public class IceCream
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private String typeOfScoop;
    private double price;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class IceCream
     */
    public IceCream()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        typeOfScoop = typeOfScoop;
        price = 1.20;
    }

    /**
     * Accessor method for the type of scoop.
     */
    public String getScoopType()
    {
        // put your code here
        return typeOfScoop;
    }

     /**
     * Accessor method for the price of the scoop.
     */
    public double getPrice()
    {
        // put your code here
        return price;
    }

    /**
     * Mutator method to set the price of the scoop.
     */
    public void setscoopType (String typeOfScoop)
    {
      typeOfScoop = typeOfScoop;
    }
}
```

#### Topping.java

```
public class Topping
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private String typeOfTopping;
    private double price;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Topping.
     */
    public Topping()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        typeOfTopping = typeOfTopping;
        price = 0.40;

    }

    /**
     * Accessor method for the topping.
     */
    public String getTopping()
    {
        // put your code here
        return typeOfTopping;
    }

     /**
     * Accessor method for the price of the topping.
     */
    public double getPrice()
    {
        // put your code here
        return price;
    }

    /**
     * Mutator method for the topping.
     */
    public void setTopping(String typeOfTopping)
    {
     typeOfTopping = typeOfTopping;

    }

}
```

#### Sundae.java

```
public class Sundae
{
    // instance variables for Sundae class.
    private IceCream typeOfScoop;
    private Topping typeOfTopping;
    private int scoops;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Sundae
     */
    public Sundae(IceCream scoopType, Topping typeOfTopping, int scoops)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        this.typeOfScoop = typeOfScoop;
        this.typeOfTopping = typeOfTopping;
        this.scoops = 0;
    }

    public double getPrice()
    {
       return typeOfScoop.getPrice() * scoops + typeOfTopping.getPrice();


    }

    public String getDetails()
    {
     return this.scoops + "scoops of" + this.typeOfScoop + "Ice Cream" +  "with " + this.typeOfTopping + "with a price of" + getPrice();
    }

}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Where is you **Main** class?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl:  The problem is apparent enough IMO without the need for `main`.

Comment: So this is a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)?...

Comment: Many weird thing in this code: missing `this` in `IceCream::setscoopType` and `Topping::setTopping`, don't use the `scoopType` argument in `Sundae`'s constructor... Typo or not typo ? May you provide the `main` entry ?

Comment: There is an error in your `Sundae` class. `this.typeOfScoop = typeOfScoop;` Should be: `this.typeOfScoop = scoopType;`

Comment: As @Mr.Polywhirl said, you need to post your `main` class. Nothing here seems to cause the compilation error that you mentioned, so the problem is elsewhere. Follow the advice given to you so far, along with this one: create a `toString()` method for each of your classes.

Comment: I should have explained it properly. To clarify my comments above, when I run the Sundae object (not class as I said above), I enter the IceCream and Topping and scoops and it comes up with the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code.

**1. Your instance variables are not properly initialized in all of the above classes.**

The constructor in the IceCream class should probably be:

```
public IceCream(String typeOfScoop)
{
    // initialise instance variables
       this.typeOfScoop = typeOfScoop;
       price = 1.20;
}
```

The constructor in the Topping class should probably be:

```
public Topping(String typeOfTopping)
{
   // initialise instance variables
      this.typeOfTopping = typeOfTopping;
      price = 0.40;
}
```

The constructor in the Sundae class should probably be:

```
public Sundae(IceCream scoopType, Topping typeOfTopping, int scoops)
{
   // initialise instance variables     
      this.typeOfScoop = scoopType;
      this.typeOfTopping = typeOfTopping;
      this.scoops = scoops;
}
```

**2. Incorrect mutator methods.**

The correct mutator method in the IceCream class should probably be:

```
public void setScoopType (String typeOfScoop)
{
     this.typeOfScoop = typeOfScoop;
}
```

The correct mutator method in the Topping class should probably be:

```
public void setTopping(String typeOfTopping)
{
     this.typeOfTopping = typeOfTopping;
}
```

**3. Incorrect Object to String conversion.**

```
public String getDetails() // Sundae class
{       
    return scoops + " scoops of " + typeOfScoop + " Ice Cream" +  " with " + typeOfTopping + " with a price of " + getPrice();
}
```

typeOfScoop and typeOfTopping variables are not Strings. Java cannot automatically convert them to the desired strings in the above method as you did not override the toString() methods in your IceCream and Topping classes.

You must either add the following two methods:

Add this to the IceCream class

```
@Override
public String toString() 
{       
    return typeOfScoop;
}
```

Add this to the Topping class

```
@Override
public String toString() 
{       
   return typeOfTopping;
}
```

OR modify the getDetails() method in the Sundae class to:

```
public String getDetails()
{   
   return scoops + " scoops of " + typeOfScoop.getScoopType() + " Ice Cream" +  " with " + typeOfTopping.getTopping() + " with a price of " + getPrice();
}
```

Hope this helps. Good luck and have fun programming!

Cheers,

Lofty

Comment: Thank you so much! This has massively helped me